# Using compiz with xmonad

Tags: ubuntu, compiz

I've been using xmonad as my windows manager in conjunction with Gnome for some time.
I would like to use compiz was well.  Is there a way to combine the two using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably interested in an alternative:

```
xcompmgr
```

see http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xcompmgr

And you will then be interested in editing your xmonad.hs and importing items such as

```
import XMonad.Hooks.*
```

here is some documentation describing some hooks

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad-contrib/0.8.1/doc/html/doc-index.html

xcompizmgr is demo software and since xmonad doesn't refresh, you will experience instability (probably in the form of certain hooks will seem to function but break after a while). But if you are really bent on putting compiz in with xmonad it is the only solution I know of.

Comment: xcompmgr is really cool and seems to work very well.  What is the reason for editing my xmonad.hs?

Answer (score 1):

Two related links, for the record:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hxpzNGppcbs (video of Compiz and Xmonad running together)

https://github.com/squarehimself/XMoniz (related code to allow this)

Now if only this code got cleaned up and integrated permanently into Compiz somehow...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do this, but you could always contact the compiz-fusion-whatevertheycallthemselvesnowafterforking team and suggest the tiling feature you're most in love with.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find some serious hurdles in your path.

xmonad is non-re-parenting window manager. This will present serious issues with the way compiz works (or xcompizmgr). I seriously doubt this will work.